# Django : automatic retry of failed database operations

Tags: django, django-models, psycopg2, psycopg3

Database operations can fail because of temporary network errors or because the database is temporarily unavailable. Is there a way to automatically retry the operation in these cases ?

The documentation of Google's managed database offering states that connection pooling systems should reconnect to the database if a connection is in a bad state, and applications should retry a database transaction if an error app in the middle of a transaction. (See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/manage-connections, section "Exponential backoff")

[Connection management](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/databases/#connection-management) with Django is clear to me, but how can I implement the second part of Google's advise using Django?

I'm currently having problems with views that successfully perform some database operations but randomly encounter a connection error during a subsequent database operation.

```
OperationalError at <url>
consuming input failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.

/.../django/forms/widgets.py, line 657, in optgroups 
657.            for index, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(self.choices):
/.../django/forms/models.py, line 1403, in __iter__ 
1403.           for obj in queryset:
/.../django/db/backends/utils.py, line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers 
80.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)
/.../django/db/backends/utils.py, line 84, in _execute 
84.         with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
/.../django/db/utils.py, line 91, in __exit__ 
91.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
/.../django/db/backends/utils.py, line 89, in _execute 
89.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
/.../psycopg/server_cursor.py, line 294, in execute 
294.                raise ex.with_traceback(None)
```

I'm not looking to *solve* this error, that would be impossible since it only happens every now and then (~0.001% of the queries) and it just means that the database is unavailable for a short time. I want to retry the database operation so that the view is finally rendered successfully.

Comment: 1) Read the *Connection management* section here [Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/databases/#connection-management) and see if any of that applies. 2) Add the, **as text**,  the complete connection error you get as update to question text.

Comment: One way would be to wrap a an `atomic transaction` in `try...except` block in a, then wrap the `try..except` block in a while loop. Couldn't that work?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: I tried different configuration parameters (`CONN_MAX_AGE` = `0`, `5` and `None` / `CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS` = True) but that doesn't address the problem, since the errors occur _after_ the connection has been opened or taken from the pool, a few queries have been executed successfully but then the database becomes unavailable for a short time.
I'll add the error message to the question text.

Comment: @McPherson : that might work, but it would mean that I have to enclose every `Model.save()` and every `Model.objects.filter(...)` code fragment in a `try ... except` block which is very impractical. I'm looking for a way to retry any database query in case the database is temporarily unavailable.